# Refresh jsp page from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm having problem with refreshing my jsp page after calling Spring controller. 
In my index page, I have login, and after the user enter username and password, the form gets submitted to the controller and then validate and create new user session. After all this, my page is refreshed and everything is working fine. The problem occur when I implement logic for changing page language. I'm doing the same but this time, the page is not refreshing! 
Here is what I have tried so far:

**JAVA CODE:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String initializeIndex(ModelMap model) {                 
    // IMPLEMENT SOME BUSINESS LOGIC HERE
    String l = (String) model.get("language");

    if (l == null) {
        l = "English";  //Default  
    }

    model.addAttribute("currentLanguage", l);
    return "index";
}

/**
 * When the user login.
 * 
 * @param model
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(ModelMap model) {

    // IMPLEMENT SOME BUSINESS LOGIC HERE

    return "redirect:/index";
}

/**
 * When the user change website language.
 * 
 * @param model
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/changeLanguage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String changeLanguage(@RequestParam String language, ModelMap model) {

    //CHANGE SITE LANGUAGE...

    model.addAttribute("language", language);           

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is how I'm calling /changeLanguage method. This function is called after a button click event.

**JS**

```
function changeLanguage(language) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "changeLanguage",
    data: "language=" + language,
    success: function(){
      alert($('#languageHolder').val());
    } 
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="languageHolder" value='<c:out value="${currentLanguage}" />'/>
```

Now when I debug the app, I see that everything is working perfect. The only difference is that when call /welcome method and the redirect to /index method, after that the index.jsp is refreshed and when call /changeLanguage method and then to /index method, the index.jsp is not refreshed.

One other difference is that on login I user form and submit the form. In change language I use ajax to submit the data to the server. Could this be the problem ? 
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I had just made some small experiments: I add one holder in my index.jsp 
and then in the controller I'm setting "language" variable to this holder. Then I
alert this value in js and observe the result. 
I just edit the code above. 
What I observe is that the JAVA code is working perfect - e.g. when there is no language set in the model, it set the default "English" and set it to the model. Also when there is such attribute, I uses it and set the new value to the model. BUT in the js, alert is always print "English" ???

Comment: How are you calling the /changeLanguage controller? Are you making a  POST request or are you making a GET request.
Are you using Jquery ajax or any other similar method to submit form data ?You will need to post the code which you are using to call changeLanguage

Comment: I'm using POST request. It's called by clicking a button.

Comment: Did you add some debug line to see if the controller is getting called.Also can you post the code you are using to call the controller

Comment: Yes. In debug I see that /changeLanguage method is calling /index method.

Comment: is your changeLanguage() located in a RESTController? Considering its also a async call why do you have it redirecting to index, all it will do is return a the whole index.jsp page to the ajax call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is RESTController. The reason for redirecting to index page is because after call /changeLanguage method, I need to refresh the index page. If there is a better approach, I will be more then happy to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Not the way I wished but still... 
The way I solved it is by create form in my jsp. In the controller I create one 
wrapper "LanguageWrapper" and add it like model attribute. 
Last, when a button is clicked, I submit the form " $('#formName').submit();" and this 
work perfectly for me. 
I still don't know my when submit with ajax the page is not refreshed and when submit the form like this it refresh. I will spend some time researching this... 
If someone knows more about this, please fill free to add more info. 
I hope my answer can help others with similar problems.